# selectedindexchanged on dynamically created gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax

I've created a gridview dynamically, now i want to fire an event when the selectedindex has changed.

```
 GridView NewDg = new GridView();
 NewDg.ID = "SubGridView" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
 NewDg.DataKeyNames = new string[]{"logentry_id"};
 NewDg.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(NewDg_SelectedIndexChanged);
 NewDg.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(NewDg_RowDataBound);
```

The RowDataBound works but it doesn't produce the right postback URL i guess.
In the RowDataBound i have the following code:

```
GridView sendingGridView = (GridView)sender;
e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(sendingGridView, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
```

this produces the following code:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('SubGridView4','Select$0')
```

Only this doesn't lead to the postback to this function:

```
        void NewDg_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GridView sendingGridView = (GridView)sender;
        ViewDetails(Convert.ToInt32(sendingGridView.SelectedDataKey["logentry_id"].ToString()));
    }
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would think the subgridview which you are suscribing events for, no longer exists in the second postback; that would be the reason for the event not raising

Comment: That sounds pretty logical, but there should also be a way to select this subgridview shouldn't it?

Comment: Well... When i have been playing with dynamic controls, the problem is they no longer exists, so my workaround is checking the Request object for watching what is actually coming from the client, and, when recreating the subgridview, to take into account these values

Comment: You can also use a hidden field modified on the client via jQuery... it would be easier also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/extgridview.aspx):

I now use a gridview in my gridview

```
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="SubGridView"
```

Because of the extender on GridView, The gridview will be displayed when I click on the plus sign (see link)

on page load i perform the following:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.RowCreated += new GridViewRowEventHandler(GridView1_RowCreated);
        GridView1.DataSource = dc.GetLogEntriesWithUsername();
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

I already have a DataBound and a Selected Index Changed event on this gridview.

On the row created event i perform the following:

```
        void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridView SubGridView = e.Row.FindControl("SubGridView") as GridView;
            List<GetLogEntriesWithUsernameByParentIdResult> subLogEntries = dc.GetLogEntriesWithUsernameByParentId(((GetLogEntriesWithUsernameResult)e.Row.DataItem).logentry_id).ToList();
            if (subLogEntries.Count > 0)
            {
                SubGridView.DataSource = subLogEntries;
                SubGridView.DataBind();
                (e.Row as ExtGridViewRow).ShowExpand = SubGridView.Rows.Count > 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

On the subgridview i also have a DataBound and a SelectedIndex Changed event. This works now!

I use this DataBound event:

```
        protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {        // only apply changes if its DataRow
        GridView sendingGridView = (GridView)sender;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // when mouse is over the row, save original color to new attribute, and change it to highlight yellow color
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover",
          "this.originalstyle=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='#C0C0C0';this.style.cursor='pointer';");

            // when mouse leaves the row, change the bg color to its original value   
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout",
            "this.style.backgroundColor=this.originalstyle;this.style.cursor='cursor'");
            //e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(sendingGridView, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex));

            e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(sendingGridView, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            e.Row.Cells[2].Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(sendingGridView, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            e.Row.Cells[3].Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(sendingGridView, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            e.Row.Cells[4].Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(sendingGridView, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            e.Row.Cells[5].Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(sendingGridView, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
```

And the selected index changed event:

```
        protected void GridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView sendingGridView = (GridView)sender;
        ViewDetails(Convert.ToInt32(sendingGridView.SelectedDataKey["logentry_id"].ToString()));         
    }
```

The ViewDetails function show the details of the selected logentry in a different div.
Now i'm busy on the final step, that is keep showing the data as it was before i clicked on a row.

Thanks for the help, but this is the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are recreating the grid on every page load?  This is a requirement for creating the grid this way.  Second, try tapping into RowCommand, and looking for the command name that way; maybe that will fire successfully; you get a reference to the command through the command argument as in :

```
void rowcmd(..) {
   if (e.CommandName != null && e.CommandName.StartsWith("Select")) {
       //Dothis
   }
}
```